# Can I make the email field required in FB App Permission screen

Tags: facebook, permissions

Can i make the email field required fieed in the FB APP Permission screen as I need to avoid getting email field value undefind?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.  Even if you could, not all Facebook accounts even have an e-mail associated with them.  Some only have a telephone number.  You will need to build your app to be able to handle not getting an e-mail address from Facebook.

Comment: Ah I see. I have subscription form with FB login so I need to get users email either manually or from FB. But is there a way of having  that email field required in some way @user3268305?

Comment: No, there really isn't any way to do that.  Typically your best bet will be to do the FB login, if email is included then press with registration.  If no email is included in the FB response, you will need to show a new form requesting a manually entered email address for your account purposes.